# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

From [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> The issue of holding fair elections is largely technical. The long-term solution will likely come from us. Still, bring up these issues in meta. There is a lot of room for innovation. Discussing the criteria of a great moderator is important and picking out potential candidates is a great way to introduce outstanding contributors to your community. And we are completely open to appointing temporary Moderators when someone’s contribution makes them a standout choice for your community’s human exception handler.

So, who should we appoint as our pro-tempore moderators for the Great Outdoors?

> **Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged**. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.”

From: [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Comment: For a really good example of a pro-tem nominations post, check out [this one from Biology](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64/who-should-the-moderators-be). Vote up the ones you want to be your leader! Self-nominations are encouraged! If you accept your nomination, *please say so!*

Answer (score 16):

My name is Kevin, and I'd like to be your moderator.

I had been waiting eagerly for this site to enter private beta, and when it did I signed in quickly. Since then, I've been helping guide the site by retagging, editing, and posting questions and answers. I  have been very active on meta as well, asking and answering the questions we need to answer.  I have been active in our chat site as well.  I am looking forward to helping this site succeed.

On other sites here, I am active on SO, Scifi, Unix, and MSO (in order of rep), and also do a lot of the maintenance - editing, retagging, etc. - on those sites also. <s>I am currently running for moderator on Scifi as well, but I've considered it and I can definitely do both, should the opportunity arise.</s> The SFF election is over, I was a close fourth, so this is not an issue.

I reside in Boston, and have a good background in sports and the outdoors here, and even more so in the Midwest where I grew up.

If you have any questions for me, come to chat, I'm often there. If you don't, come to chat and get to know us anyway.

Comment: +1 - I'd add that you've demonstrated you know lot about how the whole beta process goes, which is pretty useful at this point in this site's development!

Comment: Kevin, you've already shown a lot of leadership on this site, thanks for your work.

Comment: Thank you both, and everyone else, for your support.

Comment: +1, supported! You seem to know your stuff - both in terms of the outdoors and how the process of moderation and betas work as well.

Answer (score 15):

My name is **[studiohack](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/5)** and I'm an avid outdoors enthusiast.

I've been committed to the Area51 Great Outdoors proposal for some time, and have a user ID of **`5`**.  I participated actively in the private beta by voting, editing, asking & answering questions, and being active on Meta, as well as earning the limited `Beta` badge and earning 1K rep in 8 days.

I live and work in a remote area where Great Outdoor topics come into play every day.  Asking and answering questions this past week has made me *realize just how much of this knowledge I take for granted*.  I enjoy helping other people learn more about the great outdoors and how to enjoy it to the fullest; how to survive and live in it.

As a resident of the western United States, I can cover time zones in this part of the world.

Also, **I have a bit of previous moderator experience.**  Some of you may know me as a diamond moderator on **[Super User](https://superuser.com/)**, our Stack Exchange Q&A site for computer hardware and software enthusiasts.  I've been a moderator there for approximately a year and have gained valuable experience:

- in being a moderator,
- dealing with many different kinds of users,
- enforcing the site's FAQ & SE policies,
- voting to close, edit, etc.

Feel free to ask in SU's chat, [Root Access](http://stackexchange.com/rooms/118/) about my track record.

In summary, I would be **willing and honored** to serve as a Great Outdoors moderator and help run and shape the future of this awesome site.

*May the most deserving mods be appointed!*

Comment: +1, supported! I feel you've demonstrated a good knowledge of the outdoors as well as clearly being committed to the proposal - your previous diamond mod experience can't be a bad thing either!

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to nominate myself.  I'm active, including the administrivia like editing, tags, etc.   I've enough rep on some other SE sites to have used most of the moderator tools, so I have some experience with the system.

I was a very active promoter, sending the proposal to all of my friends and associates (five joined, and more since beta went public).  I earned the Beta badge for my full participation there.  I'm online every day.  I contribute to both questions and answers, and offer edits to improve others answers in addition to updating the wiki tags and being an active participant in discussion on both meta and chat.

I love the outdoors and want to help more people experience it.  There are a lot of scary things to someone inexperienced going out for the first (or fifth) time and I'd love to see a good QA site to help answer those questions for people.  I've spent my entire life in the outdoors and despite years of research in hiking, I'm still learning every time.

I'll spend the time and effort needed to see this become that resource.

Answer (score 6):

My name is Rory Alsop and I have always loved the outdoors. These days it's camping with my children, but getting them involved is half the fun.

My interest in the outdoors stems from a very early age, growing up in the Scottish countryside, and the mountains, stone runs and plains of the Falkland Islands, where I learned to be very self sufficient and enjoy the wilds. Not ever had to come up against large wild animals such as bears, so can't help with any information about them, but that's okay.

I have been a moderator (first pro-tem, then elected) over on Security SE since its beta back in 2010 and have been deeply committed to growing it, learning what works with the community, and helping encourage the community to continuously improve it.
The experience learned there is directly transferable here using mod powers responsibly - supporting the community, not abusing it.

I enjoy the community aspect - part of my professional life is involved directly with providing training to my community at various levels - this is a core value I hold dear.

I live in Scotland so am always on GMT or GMT+1 and generally log in before work, during lunch and in the evenings.

I would hope to be a moderator you would appreciate for my fair approach to conflict, efficient removal of spam, easily approachable and generally a helpful sort:-)

Looking forward to growing this site to a strong graduation either way!

Answer (score -4):

Of the current users I would like to nominate [Timothy Strimple](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/27/timothy-strimple) and [Hartley Brody](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/29/hartley-brody).

Their answers and edits have been very informative, spot on, and meet current best practices for outdoors experts and professionals.

It's very important for the site to have subject matter experts to filter out inaccurate answers and mis-leading questions. These two would be great candidates.

Comment: IMO -- moderators don't exist to determine the accuracy of an answer, that's what voting is for.  Mods should not completely supercede voting (ie, deleting an answer *just* because they feel it is inaccurate), but rather should be removing things that are off topic, disruptive, etc.  Wrong answers should be downvoted, NOT deleted.

Comment: Appreciate the vote of confidence! Although it seems like the community doesn't =[ Truth be told I'm a pretty busy college student and I'm not sure I'd be able to give this site the TLC it deserves anyways. But thanks for the nomination!

Comment: @HartleyBrody I wouldn't take it badly, from the upvotes on the first comment I think it's more the *reason* that was given than not agreeing with the nominations themselves :)